# How do you call a component that saves current state and then restores it?

Tags: word-request

We have a software component with the following responsibility: it saves the name of a selected visual element before executing an action and after the action finishes (with success or with failure) it selects back that visual element.
What name should we give this component?
We've discussed the options

- SelectionManager (too general)
- SelectionRestorer (sounds odd)
- Memoizer (can we use it in this context??)

Can you suggest a strong name?

Comment: Focus-restorer maybe? If you mean the component restores focus of the previously selected component. Or maybe FocusSaver?

Comment: Maybe SelectionRestorer doesn't sound that odd after all ... :-)

Comment: My 2 cents: Selection Preservation Manager (preserves user selection), Selection Persistence Manager (although persistence implies the selection is saved on the backend), Preference Persistence Manager (again .. persistence), User Personalization Persistence (in case the selection is part of a personalization feature of your software component)

Comment: @Sid: please create an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Element Saver? Element Undo?

Comment: And I can see why you had come here looking for help, but perhaps other software designers at our [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) who have encountered the issue as well would also be able to help you? Not a comment personally directed at you, but it is a comment for you :).

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang: next time I'll ask in that community, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming things, including programming variables and functions is explicitly off-topic here. See http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic